# Fastest way to extract variable width signed integer from byte[]

Tags: c#, performance, integer

The title speaks for itself. I have a file containing a base64 encoded `byte[]` of variable width integer, min 8 bit, max 32bit

I have a large file (48MB) and I am trying to find the fastest way of grabbing integers from the stream.

This is the fastest code from a perf app:

```
static int[] Base64ToIntArray3(string base64, int size)
{
    List<int> res = new List<int>();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
    {
        while(ms.Position < ms.Length)
        {
            ms.Read(buffer, 0, size);
            res.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0));
        }
    }

    return res.ToArray();
}
```

I can't see a *faster* way of padding the bytes to 32bit. Any ideas, chaps and chapettes? Solutions should be in c#. I could fall down to C/++ if i must but i don't want to.

Comment: @Ashigore The input is variable width but the output is an array of the largest width, for simplicity. A 24bit value (as is common in my domain) will be padded to 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use a memory stream to move bytes from an array to another array, just read from the array directly. Also, the size of the array is known, so there is need to add the items to a list that is then converted to an array, you can use an array from the start:

```
static int[] Base64ToIntArray3(string base64, int size) {
  byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
  int cnt = data.Length / size;
  int[] res = new int[cnt];
  for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    switch (size) {
      case 1: res[i] = data[i]; break;
      case 2: res[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(data, i * 2); break;
      case 3: res[i] = data[i * 3] + data[i * 3 + 1] * 256 + data[i * 3 + 2] * 65536; break;
      case 4: res[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, i * 4); break;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Note: Untested code! You have to verify that it actually does what it is supposed to do, but at least it shows the principle.

Comment: Could you expand upon the 24bit option? I'm not grasping it sadly :(

Comment: @Gusdor: It uses `ToUInt16` to get the first two bytes, then shifts them left by multiplying (you could use `<< 8` instead) and puts another byte after them to form the 24-bit value. Another alternative would be to get the bytes separately: `data[i*3] * 65536 + data[i*3+1] * 256 + data[i*3+2]`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work on my system. I'm using win7 x64 so it is LSB. Shouldn't only the last byte be multiplied?

Comment: @Gusdor: Right, my bad, the byte order is of course the other way around. I adjusted the code above.

Comment: Looks like a candidate for Duff's device.  Fall-through requires extra `goto case` statements in C#, but the compiled code ought to be branch-free.

Comment: Also, don't use multiply where the semantic operation is a bit-shift.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably how I would do it. Not using a stream should increase performance. This seems like the sort of thing that should be easy to do using Linq but I couldn't figure it out.

```
    static int[] Base64ToIntArray3(string base64, int size)
    {
        if (size < 1 || size > 4) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");

        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        List<int> res = new List<int>();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += size )
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, i, buffer, 0, size);
            res.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0));
        }

        return res.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I believe this is the Linq way to do this:

```
    static int[] Base64ToIntArray3(string base64, int size)
    {
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        return data.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index })
                   .GroupBy(p => p.Index / size)
                   .Select(g => BitConverter.ToInt32(g.Select(p => p.Value).Union(new byte[4 - size]).ToArray(), 0))
                   .ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is any faster than your first answer ;)

Comment: Nor am I :) But Linq has a way of optimizing, try it, it may surprise you.

Comment: It's probably faster than one expects, but as it creates a buttload of objects and arrays, it can't be very fast.